# Adding a SPFx web part to a SharePoint classic page crashes PnP Widget Wrangler AngularJS components

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have a SharePoint classic page with a Script Editor web part on it. In the Script Editor web part, I am using [PnP Widget Wrangler](https://github.com/Widget-Wrangler/ww) to add a simple AngularJS component to the page, like below:

Script Editor web part:

```
<div>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
        <br>
        Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="pnp-ww.min.js" 
          ww-appName="myApp" 
          ww-appBind="Angular"
          ww-appScripts='[{"src": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.2/angular.min.js", "priority":0},
                          {"src": "script.js", "priority":1}
          ]'>
    </script> 
</div>
```

script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

With only the Widget Wrangle component on the page, the AngularJS app loads correctly. However, when I add a basic Hello World SharePoint Framework (SPFx) web part (as described in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)) to the page, the AngularJS component that is initialised by PnP Widget Wrangler stops working. I receive the following AngularJS error:

```
Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp
```

Answer (score 0):

Some preliminary advice for this question:

1. Check the JQuery version and the load order of JQuery/AngularJS
2. Modify the angular route, remove the [].
3. Rewrite the pnp-ww.js.